# What is the log format expected by Intellij log options?

Tags: intellij-idea, logging

I have found the option in Intellij to read log files of my program and show them where the console is shown: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/setting-log-options.html A very cool feature, as I can have filtered output of some of my logs in a file and then read them in this second console.

However Intellij seems to randomly decide which of those lines are warnings and which of them are just info, therefore randomly marking some of them red. I guess I need to format the log lines in a specific way, but I cannot figure out how. The default Formatter used by the java.util.logging.FileHandler is some XMLFormat that is unreadable and the SimpleFormatter is not recognized correctly by intellij as you can see in the following picture where the only line not red is the actual only line that should be red.

[image]

Question: **Which log format is expected by Intellij to correctly display my logs?**

Comment: You can dig into the IntelliJ IDEA Community source code to find out, but I would just use [Grep Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console) plug-in instead.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I'm not experienced with grep. Doesn't it require me to know at least one word in each line that I want to see? A warning can consist of multiple lines and not all of them contain the word warning.